# Why my bcp query out not work in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm new in `sql server` and want to save select query into the csv file using with bcp query out  for that purpose write this query:

```
declare @cmd as nchar(50)
SET @cmd = 'bcp  select *from [behzad].[dbo].[behzad] queryout "d:\spt_values.dat" -U behbeh -P beh1368421 ' 
EXEC master..XP_CMDSHELL @cmd
```

but i get this output:
[image]

How can i solve this problem?thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `queryout` your source must be a query.

As a query has got blanks, you have to quote it:

Further more your `@cmd nchar(50)` is to short and will probably truncate your command.

Try this:

```
declare @cmd as nchar(500)
SET @cmd = 'bcp  "select * from [behzad].[dbo].[behzad]" queryout "d:\spt_values.dat" -U behbeh -P beh1368421 ' 
EXEC master..XP_CMDSHELL @cmd
```

With a `SELECT * FROM ...` query it was easier actually, to use the 3-part-qualified table name together with `out` instead of a `SELECT ...` with `queryout`...